# Missing controls from the Controls list in XtraUserControl

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a XtraUserControl (is a DevExpress implementation of WinForms UserControl class) with several controls inside. I have identified a memory leak when I open and close the form that contains this XtraUserControl, so I want to force the dispose of all the child controls.

I have not modified the Designer file, but there are some controls that are not in the *"this.Controls"* list. The method that I am using to get the list off all the controls can be seen below (I have tried other functions with the same result).

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control child in GetAllControls(control))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
    yield return root;
}
```

Does anyone know of any reason why some controls may be missing from the list? If I run the program I can interact with these “missing” controls.

Comment: What controls are missing?

Comment: @nempoBu4 some buttons and gridControls (all devexpress controls)

Comment: Can you create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?